# Assigning a javascript array variable to an input tags value within a loop spacing issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, spacing

I am trying to add an item within some javascript code however it seems to not like the value if it has spacing between the words.   How do I get the value to pass the full string or array object into the input tag value.

This is what I am using to assign the variable to the value.

```
   var $in = $('<input type="text" disabled name="SiteName" value='+ tempSites[i].SiteName + '>');
```

if the variable was "Happy Face"  then it would only assign "Happy" to the value and the rest comes after.

this would be the result on the page once added to the page.

```
<input type="text" disabled="" name="SiteName" value="Happy" face>
```

I have checked the variable with the alert function and the entire value "Happy Face" is stored. So I'm a bit confused.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `value="'+tempSites[i].SiteName+'"` Don't forget the double quotes

Answer (score 2):

Try using double qoutes for `value` attributes,

```
 var $in = $('<input type="text" disabled name="SiteName" value="'+ tempSites[i].SiteName + '">');
```

Comment: Thank you this helped.  Sometimes you just need someone else to take a look at something to help. :)